Count the longest streak output
Given a number, I am trying to find the longest streak of positive divisiblity into sequential smaller numbers. Here's an example:
We have this 2D list:
Transpose[{Range[18], Range[360361, 360361 + 17]}]

{{1, 360361}, {2, 360362}, {3, 360363}, {4, 360364}, {5, 360365}, {6, 
  360366}, {7, 360367}, {8, 360368}, {9, 360369}, {10, 360370}, {11, 
  360371}, {12, 360372}, {13, 360373}, {14, 360374}, {15, 
  360375}, {16, 360376}, {17, 360377}, {18, 360378}}

Notice how the first 15 sets, all the y values divide the x value nicely. So the max streak is 15 here. The streak stops at the 16th set: As 16 does not divide 360376.
I have this so far:
Cases[Transpose[{Range[18], Range[360361, 360361 + 17]}], {a_, b_} -> Divisible[b, a]]

which gives me:
{True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, False, False, True}

Here's what I like to have:

Count the max True Streaks only and stop at the first False.

Have an automated incremental expression to keep going for higher numbers beyond 360361 (So I can set how high we test) and have the same Transposed range to test for a longer streak of divisibility, to see where's the next one which matches that count or higher numbers!



you can just generate such a list of whatever length you want

New version:
This code outputs first number that has "streak" of length at least q:
fu2[q_] := (x /. 
   ToRules[Reduce[Table[x + n - 1 == n*k[n], {n, q}], Integers] /. 
     C[1] -> 1])

We can test up to length 20.
Table[{n, fu2[n]}, {n, 20}] // Column


{1,1}
{2,3}
{3,7}
{4,13}
{5,61}
{6,61}
{7,421}
{8,841}
{9,2521}
{10,2521}
{11,27721}
{12,27721}
{13,360361}
{14,360361}
{15,360361}
{16,720721}
{17,12252241}
{18,12252241}
{19,232792561}
{20,232792561}

Old code:
This outputs length of your "streak" (for x=1 it is trivially infinity).
fu[x_] := 
 Block[{i = 1}, 
  If[x == 1, Infinity, While[Divisible[x + (i - 1), i], i++]; i - 1]]

So for eaxample:
fu[360361]


15

We can test all integers up to say 400000 (avoiding x=1).
Table[{n, fu[n]}, {n, 2, 400000}];
Cases[%, {_, Max[%[[All, 2]]]}]


{{360361, 15}}

We see that 360361 is the first of length 15.
Testing up to one million.
Table[{n, fu[n]}, {n, 2, 10^6}];
Cases[%, {_, Max[%[[All, 2]]]}]


{{720721, 16}}

Up to 10^7.
Table[{n, fu[n]}, {n, 2, 10^7}];
Cases[%, {_, Max[%[[All, 2]]]}]


{{720721,16},{1441441,16},{2162161,16},{2882881,16},{3603601,16},{4324321,16},{5045041,16},{5765761,16},{6486481,16},{7207201,16},{7927921,16},{8648641,16},{9369361,16}}


Utterly amazing! @azerbajdzan ! Will study some of these commands....Cheers!

Also: I guess fu2 stops at the very first hit. For example 16 had 13 occurences, but fu2 only shows the first one...

@Steve It is stated above the code of fu2 that it outputs the first number. If you want next one use C[1] -> 2 instead of C[1] -> 1.

Would it take much to change it to output all streaks in order? ....

There are infinitely many of them for each length.

How did the last code only print streaks of 16.   Seeing it is checking up to 10^7   it's selecting how many MAXes?

DivisibleStreak[length_?(GreaterThan[1])] := 
  LCM @@ Range[length] + Range[length]

DivisibleStreak[15]
(* {360361, 360362, 360363, 360364, 360365, 360366, 360367, 360368,
    360369, 360370, 360371, 360372, 360373, 360374, 360375} *)

To get streaks of at least the same length that start at higher numbers, just take multiples of the LCM.
If you want to know how long the streak is that starts at a given number, then
DivisibleStreakLength[start_?(GreaterThan[1])] := 
  1 + LengthWhile[Differences[Divisors[start - 1]], EqualTo[1]]

DivisibleStreakLength[360361]
(* 15 *)


Looks great!  Just 1 question @lericr  your DivisibleStreak[] function just gives the streak for the FIRST one right?  So if I want to get the next ones, are you saying to get multiples of the LCM? How so....

Yes, it just gives the first one. Yes, any multiple of the LCM can be used to yield another sequence. I.e. n * (LCM @@ Range[length]) + Range[length] for any positive n.
